# How to json serialize or json deserilize object with Property IList<IOBJ>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Object with interface list property . i have a need to serialize and deserialize this object . i am using newton json for serialize it converts the object to json but when i deserailize this json to object its crate error 'Could not create an instance' . MY class is like this

```
public class GridFilterModel
{
    public IList<IFilter> Filter { get; set; }       
}
```

Comment: Why are you deserializing/serializing entire interfaces to JSON?

Answer (score 2):

That is because it does not know which type to use to deserialise an `IFilter` into (the JsonSerializer chooses a `List<>` for `IList<>` by default) - you need to use this type in the declaration, eg asssuming `Filter : IFilter`:

```
public IList<Filter> Filter { get; set; }
```

Will serialize and deserialize fine.

**Update following comment**

If you do not control the type of the filters, then I would recommend creating a DTO that has all the relevant data that you care about in it and then serialize that instead:

```
public class FilterData
{
  public FilterData(IFilter filter)
  {
    // Copy data from filter argument here into local properties.
  }
}

...

public IList<FilterData> FilterData { get; set; }
```

Comment: I cn't change ifilter object to filter because of i'm using api so from this api i received this object.